# problem with laoding image at run time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm having an image that i have added to the image folder in app_data folder 
of my application. now problem is that it's showing the image at  design time 
but at runtime it don't show.now if page  is postback now it shows the image.

what's the prob with this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put images in the App_Data folder- it is meant for storing data that is not accessible via a URL.

Move the image out of that folder and it should work fine.

Comment: thanx  sir...now its running fine.

Comment: sir can  you please see the another problem that is 
problem with login control that i posted yesterday.
please look at ttah..

Answer (score 0):

You should verify in the html code pre-postback that the image has a valid url. Aren't you setting the url only on the postback event handler?

Post the code for more help

Comment: <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/loginpic.jpeg" Height="227px" Width="362px" />

Comment: the browser will look in the image folder.... move your image in that directory and will work

Comment: thanx sir....nowits running by putting that image outside the folder.

thanx a lot.

Comment: sir can  you please see the another problem that is 
problem with login control that i posted yesterday.
please look at ttah..